# How can I change the RSS feed link for my IFTTT?

Tags: rss, ifttt

I have a site that I have set up a lot of Applets for in IFTTT. Now I have changed the domain for my site, and don't see how I can easily change the RSS-feed link (to the new domain) in IFTTT.

If I go to https://ifttt.com/feed and then click on Settings, I can disconnect the RSS feed. But I don't want to do that, just change the URL to the feed.

I have searched Google and SO, but not found the answer.

How can I change the RSS feed link for my IFTTT?

Comment: The feed URL is on a per-"applet" basis. You set the URL in the "trigger" part when setting up the "applet." You'll have to go into the individual applets' settings to edit the url.

Comment: Thank you. Didn't see it. Was thinking I had to edit it in the RSS feed setting (globally).